# Can I use my two PC on my own network to Farm Render in Blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, network

Is it possible to use Cycles engine to render only GPU based from two computers in Blender in my own network at home? TY.

Comment: Yes. This is possible.

Comment: This video explains distributed rendering with Blender.
[DIY Renderfarm Building Tutorial for Distributed Blender Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNhUnPWzVaw&t=1309s)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find out if two computers in the same network could render in Cycles the same frame or only one instance using GPU Computed feature, and not an animation or several frames. In other words the GPUs to pick up tiles of the same frame. So far I noticed it's possible the computers to pick up different frames if it's an animation going, but not same frame.  Thank you.